# Height chapter number or height chapter name in memoir

Tags: spacing, sectioning, memoir, chapters

I use `memoir` class. I want add some vertical space before chapter name or chapter number. I got that with `\beforechapskip` command, but this way add a fixed vertical space for all chapters. There are any `\command` that control height of chapter number or height of chapter name, so I can add vertical space dinamically from this `\command`?

Comment: It's not really clear what your aim is; can you add some explanations?

Comment: Well i ask if there are a command like \chapterheadingheight that control height of chapter heading to make \beforechapskip{\chapterheadingheight} or \beforechapskip{\textheight-\chapterheadingheight} ... I see this `\newlength\chaptertitleboxheight` ... `\settototalheight\chaptertitleboxheight{...}`, but I don't understand how works ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you like to change vertical space before of only one chapter head. This you can obtain width:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \setlength\beforechapskip{9\baselineskip}
   \begin{document}
\chapter{one}
\lipsum[1-2]

\setlength\beforechapskip{0\baselineskip}
\chapter{two}
\setlength\beforechapskip{9\baselineskip}
\lipsum[3-4]

\chapter{three}
\lipsum[5-6]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I use this way to add "fixed" vertical space before chapter name, and this aplies the same vertical space for all chapters. I found dinamyc vertical space from height of chapter name. (In this last way the vertical space before chapter name is not the same for all chapters). Regards

Comment: Do you try my example? I change vertical space just for one chapter. with first ``\setlength\beforechapskip{0\baselineskip}`` I reduce vertical space, with second one, immediately after `chapter{two} `` it is ``\setlength\beforechapskip{9\baselineskip}`` I return it to predefined value. My test shows, that this work. If you provide MWE, I will be able to say more.

Comment: I understand your example, that way is not dynamic, because change the the vertical space manually for each chapter. I could use that way, but I will need to calculate the vertical space before chapter headings every time ...

Comment: Basic concept of book design is that all elements like space before headings, fonts, etc in book are equal. Dynamically changed this all the time? And what is rule for this change? You still not provided a MWE which shows your effort so far. I'm not willing to guess any more.

Comment: You don't need guess nothing. the MWE will not make the difference because I ask if "there are a command" like `\chapterheadingheight` that control height of chapter heading to make `\beforechapskip{\chapterheadingheight}` or `\beforechapskip{\textheight-\chapterheadingheight}`

Comment: So you want to add `\textheight - \chapterheadingheight` before each chapter? Will the result be that the chapter is flushed down to the bottom of the page perhaps or am I missing something? I am guessing that could be done with a \vfill perhaps? But I am not sure I understand correctly, an example might make things clearer...

Comment: (+1) -- It is said to have so many unresponsive O.P.s who do not really care

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, yeah, you have right. I still remember my conversation (by comment) with OP. I have filling that I spoke to "black hole" ... thank you for up-vote!